# Change validation of kendo upload control dynamically

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-upload

Could you please help me how to change **allowedExtensions** valiation of kendo file upload control dynamically runtime using Jquery?

e.g. Suppose user select to upload the media file,
then allowedExtensions should be change to ".mp4".

```
 $("#filesFromLocal").kendoUpload({
                success: PWonSuccess,
                upload: PWonUpload,
                error: PWonError,
                multiple: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                validation: {
                    allowedExtensions: [".pdf"],
                    maxFileSize: maxFileSize
                },
                async: {
                    saveUrl: saveURL,
                    chunkSize: chunkSize,
                    autoUpload: false
                },
                remove: function (e) {
                    var fileInfo = $("#filesFromLocal").data("kendoUpload").getFiles();
                    if (fileInfo.length == 2) {
                        LocalDeletedFile = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        LocalDeletedFile = true;
                    }
                },
                select: onimportselect
            });
```

Comment: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/widget/methods/setoptions

Comment: @GaloisGirl Thanks!!! You are the Rockstar...